# chaptertitle name and chapter number in one line but diffrent edge of the page

Tags: formatting, chapters

This is what I want:

> Introduction <---all the way on the right edge of the page---> Chapter 1

But, the catch is that I have a 5cm width margin note space in a two sided document. I am working with the `book` class if that helps...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you want the string "Chapter #" to be flushed to the right edge of the page?

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `titlesec`, which works also with multiline titles:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}

\usepackage[right=5cm, showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}{\Huge\bfseries}{\rlap{\hspace*{\dimexpr\textwidth + \marginparsep}\color{IndianRed3}\chaptername{} \thechapter}}{0pt}{#1}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-3]

\setcounter{chapter}{8}
\chapter{Another chapter. \\Yet another chapter.}

\lipsum[4-6]


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `\setcounter{chapter}{10}\chapter{Introduction}`?

Comment: I only answered the O.P.'s requirements. In such a case he/she may modify the layout: change the values of `marginparwidth`, or decide the word ‘Chapter’ and chapter number will be in a tabular environment, in different rows. Inevitably there can be problem putting the label in the margin. It's up to the user to adapt the different parameters.

Comment: Where did the OP mention that the solution will be used with a document having less then ten chapters?

Comment: As I said, he  can modify the parameters so as to fit marginparwidth: setting it to 5.5cm will do. Unless he  uses Roman numbering. The code is pretty easy to adapt. Or make the label on two lines if he wants a `Chapter MDCCCXVIII`. I'm afraid there's no universal solution that works out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are most flexible if you redefine the `\@makechapterhead` by hand. (I'll add a remark with the reasons right before the complete code.)

Two parboxes, the first as wide as the `\textwidth` and the second as your right margin (5cm), side by side wrapped into a `\hbox` should do the job

```
\hbox{%
  \parbox[t]{\the\textwidth}{\Huge\bfseries\raggedright#1}
  \parbox[t]{5cm}{\huge\bfseries\raggedleft\@chapapp\space \thechapter}
}
```

[image: output-draft]

As you see 'Chapter 1' gets pushed exactly to the edge. However, I would recommend to set the second `\parbox` to a little less then your right margin. I used 4.5cm in the final solution. Additionally I would add a little offset to the width of the first `\parbox`, so the final redefinition of `\@makechapterhead` is:

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \dimen0=\dimexpr\textwidth-2em\relax
        \hbox{%
          \parbox[t]{\the\textwidth}{\Huge\bfseries\raggedright#1}
          \parbox[t]{4.5cm}{\huge\bfseries\raggedleft\@chapapp\space \thechapter}
        }
        \par\nobreak
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \vskip 40\p@
  }
}
```

[image: output-final]

Now a few remarks:

- You need the e-TeX extension to compile the code. It should be in your distro by default. I just mention it for the sake of completeness.
- With this solution you can set the `marginparwidth` without interfering with the chapter number (see the last pic).
- You are able to deal with very long chapter headings (see the last pic).

[image: extrem_cases]

Here is the complete code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[right=5cm,marginparwidth=2.5cm,marginparsep=2em]{geometry}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \dimen0=\dimexpr\textwidth-2em\relax
        \hbox{%
          \parbox[t]{\the\dimen0}{\Huge\bfseries\raggedright#1}
          \parbox[t]{4.5cm}{\huge\bfseries\raggedleft\@chapapp\space \thechapter}
        }
        \par\nobreak
      \fi
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \vskip 40\p@
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Long long long long long long long Introduction}

\marginnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```